# ggsurvplot error when trying to plot multiple datasets

Tags: r, statistics

I have a number of survfit objects from different studies that I would like to plot on the same figure.

The studies are of different length, but I cannot think of any other major differences.

Below is my code:

```
#Fitting ambristentan data
ambri_surv_fit <- survfit(Surv(event_time, censor)~1, data=ambri_mono)

#Fitting tadalafil data
tada_surv_fit <- survfit(Surv(event_time, censor)~1, data=tada_mono)

#Fitting macitentan data
maci_surv_fit <- survfit(Surv(event_time, censor)~1, data=maci_mono)

#Fitting maci_control mono data
maci_control_mono_surv_fit <- survfit(Surv(event_time, censor)~1, data=maci_control_mono)

surv_fit_list <- list(ambri_surv_fit,
                     tada_surv_fit,
                     maci_surv_fit,
                     maci_control_mono_surv_fit)

ggsurvplot(surv_fit_list, combine=TRUE)
```

The error I get:

```
Error in names(fit) <- fitnames : 
  'names' attribute [2828] must be the same length as the vector [4]
```

How I would like the figure to look:

[image]

Comment: Individually, they all plot fine without any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to name your list:

```
surv_fit_list <- list("ambirsentan monotherapy" =ambri_surv_fit,
                     "tadalafil monotherapy" = tada_surv_fit,
                     "macitentan monotherapy" = maci_surv_fit,
                     "macitentan control monotherapy" = maci_control_mono_surv_fit)
```